# GNU make file foreach loop is not working

Tags: makefile, gnu

In the GNU make file, need to have `run_options30=Pkts=30`. but it's not working.

```
list = 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58
$(foreach var, $(list),$(eval run_options$(var)=Pkts=$(var)  ) )
```

Comment: "it's not working" is not a good problem description. Tell us what you get, what you expect to get, and why you expect that.

Comment: Hi Mike.  thanks for help.  when I try to print the make file variables run_options30 ,run_options31 ,run_options32.......like  that , it is not having   variables Pkts=30 , Pkts=31 respectively. it is printing  empty string. I want these run_options to be passed to the target depending on the packet length. and  number 30, should be part of run_options30  to run the test cases.

Comment: It works for me, so the problem is elsewhere in your makefile. Please
edit your question to show a minimal makefile with which readers can reproduce the problem (a [mcve]).

Comment: thanks Mike. it is working .there is a some mistake when I executed . list  is mentioned after for each loop. but I ignored it as I thought for make file order is not important.